# Pokemon Platinum HM Glitch

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

In Pokemon Platinum, my game always makes a weird black thing on the screen whenever I use an HM. This is **not** part of the usual HM move animation. I bought this game new, and it continues to do this even if I restart the game. This does not affect game play, but I was wondering if there were any reasons behind this strange glitch.

**Edit:** This only happens outside of battle.

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you try and get a picture?

Comment: @Robotnik I'll try to get a picture later.

Comment: Just to be sure, as I'm French, does HM means "Hidden Move"?

Comment: @Tloz Oui monsieur :)

Comment: Does this happens only during fights, out fights or both?

Comment: @Tloz This only happens when I use them out of battle.

Comment: @Robotnik I forgot i asked this question. Unfortunately, I have nothing to take a picture with.

Comment: Is this the thing where you see Lucas/Dawn open a Poké Ball, see a Pokémon, and the HM is used?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Yes :)

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then that is normal. That is supposed to happen when using HMs outside of battle.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue it's not a part of the normal animation. It's probably just a weird glitch with my game or something ;-;

Comment: Can you at least try to get a picture of it? We can't help you with your question if you don't have a picture.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Strange. I opened up Pokemon Platinum after about a year of not playing it and I did not notice the glitch, so I'm closing this question. Thanks for the effort everyone!